How to distinguish contrast from simultaneity when using the connective "while"?
Considering this excerpt:

The highest grossing film of all time is by a famous director who set his story on a planet
orbiting a distant star. And it features a famous actress who plays an astrobiologist. While most branches of science have ascended in this era, the field of astrophysics persistently rises to the top. I think I know why

Source: Astrophysics for People in a Hurry by Neil deGrasse Tyson
In the sentence "While most branches of science have ascended in this era, the field of astrophysics persistently rises to the top", does the word "while" indicate contrast, or is it used as a time linker, meaning "at the same time as"? In my opinion, there is a contrast idea between the two clauses, but is it possible to discard the idea of simultaneity?

It’s pretty clearly intended to convey the connective idea of although.  For my money, the sentence is not particularly well written.

The sentence includes two time phrases: "in this era" and "persistently". You should be able to use those to work out the temporal relationship. They indicate a contrast.

Incidentally the link doesn't work for me; I think it may depend on where in the world you are. Without further context, it's hard to tell what "this era" refers to.

It's not a logical sentence, but while there is not temporal but concessive. It's about as logical as "While there are  several teams hoping for a playoff berth this season, Team X has the best record."

In case anyone is wondering, the movie he's presumably talking about is Avatar.

@StuartF I've fixed the link. "This era" refers to the time when the movie Avatar was made; it came out in 2009.

But even without a working link, doesn't the quote provide enough context? A high grossing film on a remote planet could be a Star Wars film, but they don't have any astrobiologists. Avatar is the only the only film that fits the description.


The highest-grossing film of all time is by a famous director who set
his story on a planet orbiting a distant star. And it features a
famous actress who plays an astrobiologist.
While most branches of science have ascended in this era, the field of
astrophysics persistently rises to the top. I think I know why.

(I've reformatted as I believe there is a sufficient topic-shift [essentially a refocussing onto the main argument of the dialogue] to warrant a new paragraph.)
I interpret this usage of 'while' to be the introduction of a (mildly, not massively) concessive statement, here preceding the main assertion

the field of
astrophysics persistently rises to the top [of 'popular science' fiction / dramatisation'].

A paraphrase would be

It's certainly true that most branches of science have ascended in this era, but unarguably the field of astrophysics persistently rises to the top. I think I know why.

Using the concessive markers 'Even though' and especially 'It has to be conceded that' in place of 'while' would not be as mild.
These are addressed say at
[Concessive Clauses @ The Internet Grammar of English; UCL; Link only, courtesy of Google]

... while can introduce a temporal clause: I read the newspaper [while
I was waiting]. or a concessive clause: [While I don't agree with
her], I can understand ...

[slightly more at UCL - London's Global University; Link only, courtesy of Google]]:

[While I don't agree with her], I can understand her viewpoint.

The internet (Reddit; Link only, courtesy of Google} has:

While I don't agree with her, I can understand where she's coming
from.

A mild concessive ('mitigator' in some linguists' terminology.) 'Granted that' would be slightly and 'Even though' considerably more immoderately abrupt.
This sense of 'while' is pragmatically almost demanded here. The simultaneity relationship sounds far less natural. Though a purist (hyperprescriptivist?) might demand complete disambiguation.

While [i.e., although] context usually points you to the intended meaning, ambiguity is possible. Guides on scientific and technical writing strongly advocate for avoiding while with the meaning of although, and since with the meaning of because:

Use the proper subordinating conjunctions "While" and "since" have
strong connotations of time. Do not use them where you mean
"although", "because", or "whereas".
Poor Since solvent reorganization is a potential contributor, the selection of data is very important.
Better Because solvent reorganization is a potential contributor, the selection of data is very important.
Poor While the reactions of the anion were solvent dependent, the corresponding reactions of the substituted derivatives were not.
Better Although the reactions of the anion were solvent dependent, the corresponding reactions of the substituted derivatives were not.
Janet Dodd, ed.; The ACS [American Chemical Society] Style Guide,
p.100 (1986)


While, Although, Since, Because While has long been used with the concessive connotation expressed by although, and since in the
meaning expressed by because or for the reason that. Both while
and since have a strong sense of time, and either one at the
beginning of a sentence may be ambiguous. Each of the two sentences
below has two possible interpretations: one interpretation of the
first is absurd.
While the peanuts are grown in Georgia, most of them are eaten in New York.
Since snow fell yesterday, the roads have been slippery.
Revise any sentence in which either of these words might be
ambiguous. Use a substitute word or phrase (although, but, whereas,
even though, even if instead of while; because, for, inasmuch as
instead of since). Or try making two coordinate clauses separated by a
semicolon.
The peanuts are grown in Georgia; most of them are eaten in New York.
Because snow fell yesterday, the roads have been slippery.
Edward Huth et al., eds.; Council of Biology Editors Style Manual,
p.24 (1978)


Of course, style guides for technical writing are not necessarily applicable to more casual writing. Popular writers are more likely to go by CMOS.

@Barmar True, however all writers should avoid ambiguity. And to avoid it, you need to be aware of the possible meanings. It's not always enough to think "that particular interpretation is possible but illogical, so I'm OK," because readers waste processing time regardless. // Also the U in ELU is not limited to casual English.


While most branches of science have ascended in this era, the field of astrophysics persistently rises to the top.

The vocabulary in this sentence is not very idiomatic.

The literal meaning of "ascend" has to do with  changes in level in clearly defined gradations (rise above horizon, volume of sound, station from inferior to superior); figuratively, there is still a matter of gradation involved (ascended to the throne, ascended to the peak of sporting achievement, ascend into Heaven, etc ). What is expected is something like "flourished", "reached new/unexpected heights", "thrived".

"Persistently" means "continuing for a long time, especially in a way that is annoying and that cannot be stopped"; it is not a wholly improper adverb but but it has connotations that are foreign to the context of scientific progress. "Steadily" can be used as a replacement.

"Top" implies competition; something or someone is at the top only in comparison to other things or persons, but the various sciences do not strive towards a given goal that would be common to all and no science is higher than any other. The fact that astrophysics had become a science in which the results, by their number and far reaching consequences made it interesting  more than any other science, is  approximately the idea.


Having made these adjustments in the vocabulary, so as not to let anyone suppose that the initial choice of words was wholly acceptable, the question can be given some thought.

While most branches of science progressed in this era, the field of astrophysics steadily  rose to unprecedented peaks of marvelous knowledge.

This appears to be an ambiguous statement because an adverb making precise the modality of the progress is missing or because a context is missing.
Context
Taking certain sentences such as the one in what follows, both interpretations are possible, according to the context.

While she did her homework, they did nothing and watched TV. She joined them later and they all watched TV together. (In the mean time; it seems to be the default interpretation.)

It is not surprising that she got good grades and that they failed; while she did her homework, they did nothing and watched TV. (Contrast)


Addition of an adverbial pointing to a contrast
The addition of an adverbial pointing to a contrast makes the interpretation unambiguous.

While most branches of science progressed in this era at only a normal pace, the field of astrophysics steadily  rose to unprecedented peaks of marvelous knowledge.


Even your fix contrasts pace and height.  It would be better to say "While most branches of science rose to new heights in this era, the progress of astrophysics was completely out of this world."

Taking your question to be general, I’d say that careful authors (or speakers) use grammatical parallelism in contexts where while is used with its literal temporal meaning. Thus, While most branches of science have ascended in this era, the field of astrophysics has [persistently?] risen to the top.

Precisely; for the word "while" in the given sentence to be grammatically correct, it cannot be referring to concurrency. Yet the alternative interpretation ("while" as indicating contrast) isn't logical either, given that Case B is simply a special case of Case A. A logical correction would be "In this era, most branches of science have ascended; however, the field of astrophysics persistently rises to the top", but ultimately the given sentence is just irritating and poorly constructed, as explained in LPH's answer.
